# Add reference library on multiple projects

Tags: c#, dll

I've downloaded a test solution with many Projects in it. One of the referenced library (same for all projects) is missing and needs to be added. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Simpler in reference to what?

Comment: If it's missing, it is referenced in the csproj files. Locate the path where the file SHOULD be and place it there. This may be simple for some people.

Comment: I would do automatic text replace of the reference in the `csproj` files.

Comment: @DhavalPatel - Don't tell me you want to update many (like 40) refence projects for each demo solution? @ Konrad Kokosa - That's a nice tip. Thank you.